# How to pass data from view to component in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Perhaps I don't understand some basic principle here, but I have been reading the documentation and trying out different approaches for 2 hours and I can't wrap my head around this.

So, I have a `VueJS` app, and in data I have an array named `pattern`. It looks something like:

```
[3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 8, 7, 9, 5]
```

In my view I am iterating through this array and showing a div for each element:

```
<div v-for="(ball, key) in pattern">@{{ ball }}</div>
```

Simple, right?

Now, I will be making the HTML inside this div more complex. But before I do that, I would like to make this a separate component (I might be reusing it elsewhere on the site so that approach seems to make sense).

So, in my main VueJS app I registered a new component:

```
Vue.component('rack', require('./components/Rack.vue').default);
```

I created `Rack.vue` with the following content:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- show ball number here -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {

        }
    }
</script>
```

And I tried adding a `<rack></rack>` element to the HTML inside the for loop.

But now I have no idea how to pass the `ball` data to each component. I should be showing 9 `rack` components on the page (1 for each member of the `pattern` array).

I have tried adding `v-model` to the `<rack>` element but that caused a warning. I have also tried something like a `:ball` property but this threw an error. I take it I should be using props in some way, but I am confused by the syntax and the differences between Vue 1 and Vue 2 in this regard (I am using 2.6.10).

Comment: `v-model` is only used for input elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can [pass data to a component using props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props).

```
<template>
  <div>@{{ ball }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['ball']
}
</script>
```

Then you would use your component in the view like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(ball, key) in pattern" :key="key">
    <Rack :ball="ball" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    Rack: () => import('./components/Rack.vue'),
  },
  data: () => ({
    pattern: [3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 8, 7, 9, 5]
  })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define a prop on the `rack` component and then pass the value to it
[documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)

```js
Vue.component('rack', {
  props: ['ball'],
  template: '<div>{{ball}}</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      pattern: [3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 8, 7, 9, 5]
    }
  },
  methods: {}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(ball, key) in pattern">
    <rack :ball="ball"></rack>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found this sort of syntax in a few places. What's bugging me is, why do I have to define the HTML right there (the 3rd line of your snippet)? Can't I import it from a template file instead?

Comment: @jovan Yes you can, I only have to do that there to make it runable in the snippet.

Comment: I've tried this and I get an error in the console, saying `invalid template option:[object Object]`. Strangely enough, in the Vue devtools tab, I see that `ball` has a value within the component.